# Invalid Host Name when access app in sharepoint 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I'm new to sharepoint and start to learning develope in sharepoint.

When I start deploy an app to sharepoint a local server, it deploy successful with no error.

But when I access to the app, it's always bad request: invalid host name.

I have followed many instruction to config app in sharepoint but problem is not solved.

Can anyone help me to fix it?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and Windows Server 2012 to host SharePoint 2013

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After deploying App for SharePoint your hosts file is going to be updated with appropriate records like below.

`127.0.0.1  app-93b7514a6939cb.apps.3p18    # 78f68cdc-80f8-4a75-8cc2-aa82985bc6a1;http://3p18:2121/`

`::1    app-93b7514a6939cb.apps.3p18    # 78f68cdc-80f8-4a75-8cc2-aa82985bc6a1;http://3p18:2121/`